# Postgres_fdw SELECT к одному и тому же серверу локально и удаленно отличается по скорости в сотни раз

Tags: postgresql

Имеется 2 виртуалки в локальной сети:

- разраб_сервер1 (postgres 15.1)
- разраб_сервер2 (postgres 15.1
  postgres_fdw)

SELECT разраб_сервер2 с разраб_сервер1 занимает **+- 450 ms.**

В production, где серверы удалены друг от друга, имеется тоже самое 1-в-1 (ос, архитектура, версии библиотек):

- prod_сервер1 (postgres 15.1)
- prod_сервер2 (postgres 15.1 postgres_fdw)

SELECT prod_сервер2 c prod_сервер1 занимает **+- 230000 ms**

Провёл тест: на роутере сделал перенаправление порта, а разраб_сервер2 пустил через впн, чтобы добавить затраты на соединение, наиболее приближенные к production. По итогу SELECT также как в production среде: +- 230000 ms вместо 450 ms

Понимаю, что затраты на установление соединения имеют место быть, но не такие же. За это время, пока выполняется запрос, можно было всю базу целиком раз 100 перенести с одного сервера на другой.

Сам запрос:

```
SELECT
            orders.member_id,
            orders.public_id,
            orders.alias,
            orders.created,
            COALESCE(temp_table.unread, 0) as unread_messages,
            members.fullname as member_fullname,
            members.email as member_email,
            members.cellphone as member_cellphone,
            countries.name_ru as member_country,
            members.registered_epoch as member_registered_epoch
        FROM orders
        LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
            SELECT 
            COUNT(*) as unread,
            related_order_id
            FROM order_messages
            WHERE
            related_order_id = orders.id
            AND send_by_member_id IS NOT NULL
            AND id > COALESCE(( SELECT 
                last_read_message_id
                FROM messages_read 
                WHERE 
                related_order_id = orders.id 
                AND read_by_admin_id = :user_id
                LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
            ), 0)
            AND status = 'show'
            AND created_epoch > :created_admin_time

            GROUP BY related_order_id
        ) temp_table
        ON orders.id = temp_table.related_order_id
        INNER JOIN
            members
        ON
            orders.member_id = members.id
        INNER JOIN
            countries
        ON
            members.country = countries.iso_code
        ORDER BY orders.id ASC
```

Результаты EXPLAIN:

```
QUERY PLAN    via VPN
                                                                                                                                                                                         
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=377.73..377.74 rows=1 width=1190) (actual time=273119.898..273119.914 rows=76 loops=1)
   Output: orders.member_id, orders.public_id, orders.alias, orders.created, (COALESCE(temp_table.unread, '0'::bigint)), members.fullname, members.email, members.cellphone, countries.name_ru, members.reg
istered_epoch, orders.id
   Sort Key: orders.id
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 39kB
   Buffers: shared hit=3
   ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=304.74..377.72 rows=1 width=1190) (actual time=4781.491..273119.261 rows=76 loops=1)
         Output: orders.member_id, orders.public_id, orders.alias, orders.created, COALESCE(temp_table.unread, '0'::bigint), members.fullname, members.email, members.cellphone, countries.name_ru, members
.registered_epoch, orders.id
         Inner Unique: true
         ->  Foreign Scan  (cost=100.00..127.58 rows=1 width=1182) (actual time=2189.100..2189.189 rows=76 loops=1)
               Output: orders.member_id, orders.public_id, orders.alias, orders.created, orders.id, members.fullname, members.email, members.cellphone, members.registered_epoch, countries.name_ru
               Relations: ((office1.orders) INNER JOIN (office1.members)) INNER JOIN (office1.countries)
               Remote SQL: SELECT r1.member_id, r1.public_id, r1.alias, r1.created, r1.id, r4.fullname, r4.email, r4.cellphone, r4.registered_epoch, r6.name_ru FROM ((public.orders r1 INNER JOIN public.m
embers r4 ON (((r1.member_id = r4.id)))) INNER JOIN public.countries r6 ON (((r4.country = r6.iso_code))))
         ->  Subquery Scan on temp_table  (cost=204.74..250.13 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=3564.859..3564.859 rows=1 loops=76)
               Output: temp_table.unread, temp_table.related_order_id
               Filter: (orders.id = temp_table.related_order_id)
               ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=204.74..250.11 rows=2 width=12) (actual time=3564.854..3564.854 rows=1 loops=76)
                     Output: count(*), order_messages.related_order_id
                     Group Key: order_messages.related_order_id
                     InitPlan 1 (returns $1)
                       ->  Limit  (cost=100.00..104.74 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=1779.808..1779.809 rows=1 loops=76)
                             Output: messages_read.last_read_message_id
                             ->  Foreign Scan on office1.messages_read  (cost=100.00..104.74 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=1193.903..1193.903 rows=1 loops=76)
                                   Output: messages_read.last_read_message_id
                                   Remote SQL: SELECT last_read_message_id FROM public.messages_read WHERE ((related_order_id = $1::integer)) AND ((read_by_admin_id = 1))
                     ->  Foreign Scan on office1.order_messages  (cost=100.00..145.34 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=2980.692..2980.694 rows=3 loops=76)
                           Output: order_messages.id, order_messages.related_order_id, order_messages.send_by_member_id, order_messages.send_by_admin_id, order_messages.message, order_messages.external_l
ink, order_messages.related_to, order_messages.related_id, order_messages.created_epoch, order_messages.status, order_messages.status_updated, order_messages.status_updated_by_admin_id
                           Filter: ((order_messages.id > COALESCE($1, 0)) AND (order_messages.status = 'show'::public.order_message_status))
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 3
                           Remote SQL: SELECT id, related_order_id, status FROM public.order_messages WHERE ((send_by_member_id IS NOT NULL)) AND ((created_epoch > 1671521644)) AND ((related_order_id = $
1::integer))
 Query Identifier: -5688927605033658977
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=204 read=20
 Planning Time: 8.186 ms
 Execution Time: 281665.460 ms
(34 rows)
```

```
QUERY PLAN     via LOCAL  
                                                                                                                                                                                   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=353.89..24620.05 rows=73 width=2152) (actual time=15.686..447.897 rows=76 loops=1)
   Output: orders.member_id, orders.public_id, orders.alias, orders.created, COALESCE(temp_table.unread, '0'::bigint), members.fullname, members.email, members.cellphone, countries.name_ru, members.regis
tered_epoch, orders.id
   Inner Unique: true
   ->  Foreign Scan  (cost=100.00..206.48 rows=73 width=2144) (actual time=8.699..8.808 rows=76 loops=1)
         Output: orders.member_id, orders.public_id, orders.alias, orders.created, orders.id, members.fullname, members.email, members.cellphone, members.registered_epoch, countries.name_ru
         Relations: ((office1.orders) INNER JOIN (office1.members)) INNER JOIN (office1.countries)
         Remote SQL: SELECT r1.member_id, r1.public_id, r1.alias, r1.created, r1.id, r4.fullname, r4.email, r4.cellphone, r4.registered_epoch, r6.name_ru FROM ((public.orders r1 INNER JOIN public.members
 r4 ON (((r1.member_id = r4.id)))) INNER JOIN public.countries r6 ON (((r4.country = r6.iso_code)))) ORDER BY r1.id ASC NULLS LAST
   ->  Subquery Scan on temp_table  (cost=253.89..334.42 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=5.769..5.769 rows=1 loops=76)
         Output: temp_table.unread, temp_table.related_order_id
         Filter: (orders.id = temp_table.related_order_id)
         ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=253.89..334.41 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=5.765..5.765 rows=1 loops=76)
               Output: count(*), order_messages.related_order_id
               Group Key: order_messages.related_order_id
               InitPlan 1 (returns $1)
                 ->  Limit  (cost=100.00..153.89 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=2.839..2.840 rows=1 loops=76)
                       Output: messages_read.last_read_message_id
                       ->  Foreign Scan on office1.messages_read  (cost=100.00..153.89 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=2.162..2.162 rows=1 loops=76)
                             Output: messages_read.last_read_message_id
                             Remote SQL: SELECT last_read_message_id FROM public.messages_read WHERE ((related_order_id = $1::integer)) AND ((read_by_admin_id = 1))
               ->  Foreign Scan on office1.order_messages  (cost=100.00..180.50 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=5.068..5.070 rows=3 loops=76)
                     Output: order_messages.id, order_messages.related_order_id, order_messages.send_by_member_id, order_messages.send_by_admin_id, order_messages.message, order_messages.external_link, o
rder_messages.related_to, order_messages.related_id, order_messages.created_epoch, order_messages.status, order_messages.status_updated, order_messages.status_updated_by_admin_id
                     Filter: ((order_messages.id > COALESCE($1, 0)) AND (order_messages.status = 'show'::public.order_message_status))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 3
                     Remote SQL: SELECT id, related_order_id, status FROM public.order_messages WHERE ((send_by_member_id IS NOT NULL)) AND ((created_epoch > 1671521644)) AND ((related_order_id = $1::int
eger))
 Query Identifier: 2046510771872689855
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=158
 Planning Time: 2.356 ms
 Execution Time: 451.881 ms
(29 rows)
```

Как считаете в чем может быть проблема? Куда копать?

Comment: я конечно не шарю в указанной СУБД как и как они там друг с другом удаленно взаимодействуют, но у вас в дебрях джойнов и подзапросов висит фраза `REMOTE SQL`, это оно подзапросы на удаленный сервер делает N раз? тогда наверно не удивительно что долго?
Нельзя как то это по другому реализовать, а-ля взять нужную часть данных с удаленного сервера один раз, сложить во времянку и работать с ней?

Comment: Избавляйтесь от всех подзапросов. Тем более латеральных - ведь такой подзапрос выполняется на удалённом сервере для каждой отдельной записи...

Comment: Да, запрос не идеален, буду оптимизировать. Но, почему в локальной сети 450 ms, а в production 250 000 ms? Ведь соединение устанавливается 1 раз для запроса. В локалке скорость 100 мбит, а между production серверами 90-95 Мбит.